# Ground bounce over long cables

Tags: power, batteries, brushless-dc-motor

I'm working with a 72 V battery that is driving a brushless motor under fairly high current applications, approx. 60 A(rms).

I am working to mitigate issues, I believe from ground bounce, that occur when I add in a 12 ft cable between my battery and driving electronics.

I'm curious what solutions there are that can help improve power integrity over such a long cable.

Also, what tools exist to simulate or model these.

Comment: What size cables are you using for those high currents? What is the use case? What does the power distribution network look like? You can get a good idea of voltage drop across the cable length depending on conductor size and type. https://www.inchcalculator.com/wire-gauge-size-and-resistance-calculator/

Comment: You have noted that your current is 60A RMS but what about peak current?  DC motors can draw significantly more than their average current at startup.

Comment: Measure motor DCR and compute cable R from AWS tables

Comment: There is a voltage drop for both conductors of your 12 ft cable. If you reference to the GND directly at your battery, the voltages at the end of the cable would bounce under load for  instance from 0 V up to 10 V and from 72 down to 62 V, so the motor sees only 52 V instead 72 V. If the cable is much too thin, you may get even lower voltages at the far end.

Comment: I would recommend to calculate the voltage drop over your 12ft cable at a current of 60 A. Just a simple application of Ohm's law. A resistance of 0.01 Ohm for instance would cause a drop of 0.60 V, but a cable with 0.1 Ohm a drop of 6 V. You would need a thick cable and very good connections between the cable, the battery terminals and the driving electronics.